# Find all DateTime objects in array recursively and format it

Tags: php, datetime

I want to find all objects which are instances of Datetime class and then use `format()` method in each.

I tried this, but this doesn't work recursively. Does anyone have an idea why? How can I do this?

```
<?php

namespace MyNamespace;

class MyClass {

    public function convertDate(&$item)
    {
        foreach ($item as $k => $v) {
            if (is_array($v)) {
                $this->convertDate($v);
            } elseif ($v instanceof \Datetime) {
                $item[$k] = $v->format('d/m/Y');
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried it without passing $item by reference? Do you really need that for this kind of task?

Comment: What do you mean by recursive ? Do you mean you have a multidimensional array ?

Comment: @larsAnders: A ``\`` before the beginning of a function represents the Global Namespace. It is a PHP 5.3+ feature. See [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php).

Comment: Can you give an example of the array you're trying to process?

Comment: @larsAnders The slash in Datetime is because I use namespaces. But i found by myself. Instead of `$this->convertDate($v)` I need `$this->convertDate($item[$k])` Thats working now. Thank you all

Comment: @AlfredoCosta: Don't edit it into your question. Please add that as an **Answer**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The solution

I'm calling convertDate() method in array key, but I need to pass the argument array[key] so I changed `$this->convertDate($k)` to `$this->convertDate($item[$k])`

```
<?php

namespace MyNamespace;

class MyClass {

    public function convertDate(&$item)
    {
        foreach ($item as $k => $v) {
            if (is_array($v)) {
                $this->convertDate($item[$k]); // the problem was here, now its working
            } elseif ($v instanceof \Datetime) {
                $item[$k] = $v->format('d/m/Y');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for finding the solution to your own problem. Cheers and welcome to Stack Overflow!